# CORS Error when React App tries to connect via SignalR to .NET CORE Web App having Windows Authentication enabled

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, cors, signalr, windows-authentication

I am trying to send data from React App to .NET Core Web App using SignalR.
The .NET Core Web App has Windows Authentication enabled. With Windows Authentication enabled, I am getting the CORS error when my React App tries to send message to .NET Core App via SignalR.
It works fine if I disable windows authentication and enable anonymous authentication.

Can you please help me with your valuable inputs to make the connection work?

React JS app code looks like below:

```
const hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(window.config.APP_URL, options)
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build();

    this.setState({ hubConnection }, () => {
      this.state.hubConnection
        .start()
        .then(() => console.log("SignalR Connection started!"))
        .catch((err) =>
          console.log("SignalR Error while establishing connection :(", err)
        );
    });
  }

  sendMessage = () => {
    console.log("sendMessage() Properties: ", this.props);

    const signalRMessage = {
      UserName: this.props.userName,
    };
    this.state.hubConnection
      .invoke("SendMessage", signalRMessage)
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };
```

I tried to explicitly add the ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header as shown below. But still I see the CORS error.

```
componentDidMount() {

    let options = {
      httpClient: {
        post: (url, httpOptions) => {
    
          // httpOptions.headers = {
          //   ...httpOptions.headers,
          //   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": window.config.CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN_URL,
          //   //"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, HEAD",
          // };
          // httpOptions.method = "POST";
          // httpOptions.url = url;
    
          // return httpOptions;

          const headers = {
            ...httpOptions.headers,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": window.config.CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN_URL,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, HEAD",
          };
          let newResponse = {};
    
          return axios.post(url, {}, { headers }).then(response => {
            return (newResponse = {
              statusCode: response.status,
              statusText: response.statusText,
              content: JSON.stringify(response.data)
            });
          });
    
        }  
      } 
    };
```

Below is the CORS error that I see in console logs at React App side:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZmVl.png)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("ClientPermissionPolicy", policy =>
                {
                    
                    policy.WithOrigins("https://xxxx.com")
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials();
                });
            });            

            ...
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseCors("ClientPermissionPolicy");       

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapHub<TapHub>("/hubs/tap");
            });

                     
        }
```

Went through many posts here in stackoverflow and tried below but in vain.

- In Configure():

  app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://xxxx.com").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
- In ConfigureServices():

  services.AddCors(options =>
  {
  options.AddPolicy("ClientPermissionPolicy", policy =>
  {
  policy.WithOrigins("https://xxxxx.com")
  .AllowAnyHeader()
  .AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials()
  .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true);
  });
  });
- Tried AllowAnyOrigin()
- Tried removing AllowCredentials()

Like I said above, it works fine if I disable windows authentication and enable anonymous authentication. The React App successfully connects to the hub endpoint in case of anonymous authentication. The CORS error comes into picture only when I enable windows authentication. I need Windows Authentication enabled for my requirement. Requesting you to help fix the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, however I faced similar problem right now. Even with enabled CORS, it still rejected me. In the end, I found out that problem is in the

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

When I included CORS into this part, it started to work ... finally

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors("ClientPermissionPolicy");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to place UseCors between UseRouting and UseAutorization

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("ClientPermissionPolicy");      
app.UseAuthorization();
```

and maybe you can try to move AddCors to the top of ConfigureServices method

Just the test pourposes I would use this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("ClientPermissionPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
.....
}
```

only if it works, I would try to use specific origins.

Comment: Thanks @Serge/ Tried the same but I still get the CORS error.

_Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44332/hubs/tap/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1' from origin 'https://xxxxxx.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource._

I placed UseCors between UseRouting and UseAutorization and moved AddCors to the top of ConfigureServices method.

Comment: @SiddN I updated my answer,  you can try again.

Comment: Thanks. Tried this. Still getting the same CORS error. :(

Answer (score 0):

For those using .NET Core 3.1, here is a COMPLETE solution (front-end to back-end):

My problem: When I enabled the windows authentication on my web API, I could not do fetch calls from my react app to my .NET Core 3.1 web API, CORS was freaking out. With Anonymous authentication it worked, but not when windows authentication is enabled.

**1.launchSettings.json**

this will be used only for your dev environnment, make sure windows auth is also enabled in IIS on your prod server.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58747",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
 {... more settings if any}
}
```

**2.Startup.cs:**

CORS policy is enabled here. The order of methods is important here. Also, you don't need to set those in a web.config

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", //give it the name you want
                       builder =>
                       {
                            builder.WithOrigins( "http://localhost:3000", //dev site
                                                "production web site"
                                               .AllowAnyHeader()
                                               .AllowAnyMethod()
                                               .AllowCredentials();
                       });
    });

    //database services here

    services.AddControllers();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseRouting();

    // global policy same name as in the ConfigureServices()
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

**3.Controller(s):**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
... your other usings

namespace ProjectTest.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")] //THIS HERE needs to be the same name as set in your startup.cs
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class FooController:Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("getTest")]
        public JsonResult GetTest()
        {
            return Json("bar");
        }
    }
}
```

**4.React Component fetch call example:**

The "credential: 'include'" is the secret

```
await fetch('http://localhost:3000/Foo/getTest', {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include'
}).then(resp => resp.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/3188#issuecomment-432766027), the problem takes place because:

> IIS's Windows Auth happens before ASP.NET Core runs, the ASP.NET Core
> CORS implementation isn't able to process the OPTIONS request (because
> the browser won't send your Windows credentials with it). The only
> real solution here is to use the IIS CORS module since it runs before
> Windows Authentication and can process the unauthenticated CORS
> request.